# Which tag is preferred: emulation or emulator?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-original-fallout-and-fallout-2-working-on-a-mac) earlier which I tagged emulation. Another user posted a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355/how-to-play-amiga-games-on-pc) tagged emulator. Which is the preferred, and should I go ahead and retag whichever question turns out to be using the "non-preferred?"

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a strong enough distinction between questions about emulation and questions about emulators to warrant keeping two separate tags.

To that end, a question that is about emulation is not necessarily about emulators themselves, but all questions about emulators themselves are about emulation. So I would suggest [emulation].

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the harm in both. Emulation is the general topic ("what software is best for Amiga emulation?"), whereas an emulator could be talking about a specific bit of software ("How do I configure DOSBox for X-Wing vs TIE Fighter?").

Comment: I agree. On SO there's plenty tags that synonymous. They're just left there.